# Algebraically slice implies slice

Tags: geometric-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

I am studying an article by Livingston ("New examples of non-slice, algebraically slice knots", *Proceeding of the AMS, 2001*) about an example of an infinite class of knots which are algebraically slice but not slice; I recall that a knot $K$ is slice if it bounds a smooth embedded disk in $B^4$, and that it is *algebraically slice* if its Seifert form admits a *metabolizer*, which is an half-dimensional summand $H$ of the first homology group of a Seifert surface $F$ such that the restriction of the Seifert form to $H$ is null.

In the article is claimed that, given an algebraically slice knot $K$, if its metabolizer admits as a basis a link of slice knots which bound disjoint smooth embedded disks in $B^4$, then *it is easily shown that $K$ is slice*. Probably it is easy indeed, but I am not understanding this point. Any help (also references) would be appreciated.

Comment: If such a slice link $L \subset F$ exists, then you can perform ambient surgery on $F \subset D^4$ along $L$. The result of this surgery is a disk in $D^4$ with boundary $K$. It follows that $K$ is slice. Links representing such a metaboliser are sometimes called "derivatives".

Comment: Is it necessary that the curves are a basis for the metabolizer? Or it is sufficient that they are linearly indipendent elements of the first homology group that bound disjoint slice disks?